# Basic module on a ring properties proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am studying modules $M$ on rings with units $A$ and it is given as an exercise to prove the following from basic properties of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)): $a\in A, x,y \in M$

(1) $a \cdot 0_M = \cdot 0_M $

(2) $a \cdot (x-y) = a \cdot x - a \cdot y  $

(3) $0_A \cdot x = 0_M  $

(4) $(a-b) \cdot x = a \cdot x - b \cdot x$

It is quite clear to me how to prove them if I consider the ring homomorphism $\alpha : A \to End(M) $ and I re-define all the properties. For instance, (1) comes from

$ a \cdot 0_M = \alpha(a)(0_M) = f(0_M) = 0_M$ where $f = \alpha(a)\in End(M)$

What I would like to do is to prove them only by using the definition. Is there any book in which this simple exercise is solved or explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, 
$$a \cdot 0_M = a \cdot (0_M + 0_M) = a\cdot 0_M + a\cdot 0_M,$$
whence $a\cdot 0_M=0_M$.

To prove the second assertion note that both $A$ and $M$ are groups, where $x-y$ is, by definition, $x+(-y)$.
Thus,
$$a \cdot (x - y) = a \cdot (x + (-y)) = a\cdot x + a \cdot (-y),$$
and as $$a \cdot (-y) = a \cdot (-1\cdot y) = (a \cdot (-1)) \cdot y = -a\cdot y,$$
we get 
$$a\cdot (x-y) = a\cdot x - a\cdot y.$$

The third is similar to the first, and the fourth to the second.

Comment: Just one question: what is the meaning of $-1$ in rings? As it is not part of the formal definition

Comment: @ele Wasn't it a ring with unit? If it has a unit $1$, then it has its additive inverse $-1$, because if $(A,+,\cdot)$ is a ring, then $(A,+)$ is an Abelian group.

Comment: Yes, but shall we prove that $-y = (-1) \cdot y$ ? (It seems quite simple actually)

Comment: @ele Can you see that $x+(-1)x=1x+(-1)x=0$, and what follows?

Comment: Yes, now I think I am able to put all the pieces together! Thank you!

Comment: @ele Not specific to this question, but since you are still a new user, let me bring your attention to this link: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and the other links in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). As it says in the first one, "Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well." But to keep the site tidy it is better to accept an answer, if you think it sorted you out. Good luck!